# How to change the gap between arrow and text

Tags: arrows

```
\documentclass[fleqn,12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{chemarrow}
\newcommand\Ra{$\autorightarrow{\scriptsize{Text over arrow}}{} $}
\begin{document}
\Ra 
\end{document}
```

As shown in the image, is it possible to change the gap between the arrow and the text over the arrow. Thanks for your help. 
[image]

Comment: Could you update the question so that only the examples are images, as currently most of the question is also in the image. That will make it harder to search for this information in the future.

Comment: @Joseph - Even in the image I have the same / similar text for question. the only left out part is "As of now I can produce text as shown above, how to do as shown below "

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done using a `\raisebox` with a negative value.

```
   \newcommand\Ra{$\autorightarrow{\scriptsize\raisebox{-1.5ex}[0pt][-1.5ex]{Text over arrow}}{} $}
```

**Result:** (old on top, new below; with surrounding `\fbox`)

[image]

Comment: Doesn't work. It just makes the enclosing box deeper, and pushes it up.

Comment: Works if the optional arguments of `\raisebox` are used.

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten about that.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 6):

```
$\autorightarrow{\vbox{\hbox{\scriptsize Text over arrow}\vskip-5pt}}{} $
```

Comment: if possible could you please explain what `\vbox` & `\hbox` do?

Comment: @Aku: They are the TeX primitives for creating vertical boxes (`\mpage` and the `minipage` environment use `\vbox`) and horizontal boxes (`\mbox` is based on `\hbox`). I need the TeX primitives here, as the corresponding LaTeX macros do stuff that get in the way of the intended purpose in this case.

Answer (score 3):

I apologise if you have already considered this, but the `mhchem` package has excellent facilities for over-and-under annotation of a variety of arrows (left, right, resonance, equilibrium etc.), with good default spacing.

Comment: this is an excellent package

Comment: The package runs well in linux (texlive) but in Windows I have not managed to compile (although I followed the instructions of the forums)